# mhddfs fuse: device not found, try 'modpd fuse' first

Tags: linux, device, centos7, fuse

I want to combine `/dev/sda2` with `/dev/sdb3` using `mhddfs` but can not I have installed fuse and others but can not. how to help please help
this my command:

```
[root@ns540490 ~]# mhddfs /pool/storage01,/storage /Uploads -o allow_other
mhddfs: directory '/pool/storage01' added to list
mhddfs: directory '/storage' added to list
mhddfs: mount to: /Uploads
mhddfs: move size limit 4294967296 bytes
fuse: device not found, try 'modprobe fuse' first
[root@ns540490 ~]# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2       3.6T  2.7T  769G  78% /
devtmpfs        7.7G     0  7.7G   0% /dev
tmpfs           7.7G     0  7.7G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           7.7G   17M  7.7G   1% /run
tmpfs           7.7G     0  7.7G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sdb3       3.6T  2.7T  987G  74% /storage
tmpfs           1.6G     0  1.6G   0% /run/user/0
[root@ns540490 ~]# modprobe fuse
[root@ns540490 ~]#
```

Answer (score 0):

I see few problems with what you are doing:

1. After loading fuse kernel module (`modprobe fuse`), you need to try to mount the fuse filesystem again.
2. You should not be actually using `mhddfs`, as [the author no longer maintains it and suggests to use mergerfs instead](https://github.com/trapexit/mhddfs).